# What's wrong with this in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

```
.bookmarkmenu
{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#ff4b4b;
    height:60px;
    width:100px;
    z-index:15;
    left:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.bookmarkmenu:hover
{
    background-color:#ff4b4b;
    height:60px;
    width:140px;
}

#bookmark_element
{
    top:80px;   
}


<div class="bookmarkmenu" id="bookmark_element">
    All
</div>
```

It shuold be a the left of page over other elements. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE. It put them at the end of page. hover also not function...

Comment: Um, which IE, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're in IE7 or older, `position:fixed` is invalid. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-fixed

Also, in newer versions of IE, you must specify `<!doctype html>`.

Comment: If you're in IE7 or older you should be banned from internet :P

Comment: @Martijn that's funny, coming from someone whose website still supports IE6. Sorry for offtopic.

Comment: I am not. It is 10th. And the problem was that I forgot to put <!DOCTYPE html> at the beginning.

Comment: @Frits, heheh very clever. It's an old webpage, we havent touched it in a while, if we would, that would've been long gone. New website is online any day now :P

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to put

> DOCTYPE html

at the beginning. It work now.